# Search recursively for file without it being the current directory

Tags: batch-file

I want to recursively search for all `*.pst` files in a directory on a network drive.

`dir /s/b *.pst` only searches within the current directory.

How can I specify the directory to search in?

Comment: Do I now need to delete this question, preventing other users from finding this next time someone has the same question, to get my rep back, because someone didn't like my question? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir /s/b "startingdriveanddirectoryname\*.pst"
```

eg

```
dir /s/b "M:\start here\*.pst"
```

should find your files.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `dir` there is also the [`where`](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html) command:

```cmd
where /R "\\server\share\remote\starting\directory" "*.pst"
```

or:

```cmd
where /R "D:\local\starting\directory" "*.pst"
```

or:

```cmd
where /R "D:\\" "*.pst"
```

(two backslashes are needed here for the following `"` not to appear escaped)

Comment: This works fine when you want to search a directory, but the answer my Magoo below works for directories and also drives (eg. H:\)

Comment: `where` works for drives too, but, opposed to `dir`, you must double the trailing `\ `like this: `where /R "D:\\" "*.pst"` (otherwise the following `"` is escaped)

Answer (score -2):

find directory -name '*.pst'

This will search for all the subdirectories for *.pst files.